# how to specify download folder with get-iplayer

Tags: shell, command-line

I am making a gui for `get_iplayer`. (Code [here](https://github.com/mswift42/beebster))

According to the man page for get-iplayer, I can specify a download destination with

```
get-iplayer -g `index` --output="/some/desired/folder/"
```

This works, if I type the absolute path, i.e `--output="/home/severin/Videos/"`, I get the desired result. However, I want to specify a path, that would be viable for other users too, i.e.

`--output="~/Videos"`

Unfortunately, this does not work at all. It creates a new folder in my current directory, for example, if I'm in directory "~/Pictures/", the above command will create a new directory `"/home/severin/Pictures/~/Videos"`.

Is this a bug in get-iplayer or am I doing it wrong?

Edit: get-iplayer is a perl command line program, to record BBC's Iplayer programmes.

Comment: Tilde expansion is a shell feature – what shell are you using, or are you using none? Could you post the specific code where you are actually invoking `get_iplayer`?

Comment: I'm using bash. I'm invoking it with inferior-shell:run/s from a common-lisp program, however, the outcome is the same when using bash and `get-iplayer -g 123 --output="~/Videos".

Comment: It has nothing to do with common lisp. I'd like to use it for a project written in common lisp, but it already fails to work using bash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tilde expansion rules are amazingly complicated

```
$ echo ~          # normal expansion
/home/amon
$ echo ~/foo      # exp at beginning of path
/home/amon/foo
$ echo ~foo       # but must be followed by a slash
~foo
$ echo foo/~      # not at the end of a path
foo/~
$ echo foo=~      # expansion ok after non-word char
foo=/home/amon
$ echo foo=~/foo  # can extend the path further
foo=/home/amon/foo
$ echo "~"        # no expansion inside quotes
~
$ echo -foo=~     # not when token begins with non-word character
-foo=~
```

The `$HOME` variable works in all these circumstances:

```
$ echo $HOME; echo $HOME/foo; echo foo/$HOME; echo "$HOME"; echo --foo=$HOME;
/home/amon
/home/amon/foo
foo//home/amon
/home/amon
--foo=/home/amon
```

You therefore want the command to contain `--output=$HOME/Videos` or equivalent. Please be aware that this is not completely portable: While English, end-user oriented systems will likely have a `Videos` folder in the home directories, this may not be the case under other locales or OSes.

Comment: Thanks, but this still doesn't work. Using the command `get-iplayer -g 123 --output=~/Videos` ,it will create a directory "~" in my working directory, and a subdirectory "Videos" and store the video there.

Comment: @severin The shell is sometimes annoying with all these smart features when it doesn't DWIM. I edited my answer to use the `$HOME` variable. This should hopefully work better.